# Python Selenium get attribute 'href' error

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get href from the link, please find my codes:

```
url ='http://money.finance.sina.com.cn/bond/notice/sz149412.html'
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='blk01'])//ul//li[3]//a[contains(text(),'发行信息']").get_attribute('href')
print(link)
```

error

```
 invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression 
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@class='blk01'])//ul/li[3]//a[contains(text(),'发行信息']' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Seems it is not a valid xpath, but I cannot figure out the error, any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: can you show us the error output?

Comment: please find my updated question

Answer (score 2):

```
//a[contains(text(),'发行信息')]
```

Even this would work.

```
print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

```py
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="blk01"]//ul//li[3]//a[contains(text(), "发行信息")]')
print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: Hi , thank you for your help! it worked. May I also ask is  ```get_attribute()``` not the same syntax as ```.text()```? so I cannot use this

Comment: element.text not text().

Answer (score 0):

```
# Importing necessary modules
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

# WebDriver Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Target URL
url = 'http://money.finance.sina.com.cn/bond/notice/sz149412.html'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="blue" and contains(text(),"发行信息")]').get_attribute('href')
print(link)
```

Comment: thank you so much! it worked, may I ask why my code does not work? ```('//a[contains(text(),"发行信息"]')```

Comment: @ur welcome, u did mess up with ' and ' that's why it was invalid in ur case

Comment: @Joyce please consider accepting one of the solutions, to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[@class='blk01'])//ul//li[3]//a[contains(text(),'发行信息']
```

does not seem to be a stable xpath and also **you mess up with ' and "**. This is the main problem.

Try this first:

```
find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="blk01"])//ul//li[3]//a[contains(text(),"发行信息"]')
```

If it works, try just:

```
find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),"发行信息"]')
```

The goal is to make `xpath` as short as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason to use Selenium here? It's present in the html source, so would be more efficient to use `requests` and `beautifulsoup`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://money.finance.sina.com.cn/bond/notice/sz149412.html'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


a_tag = soup.select_one('a:contains("发行信息")') 
#a_tag = soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("发行信息")') # <- depending what version of bs4 you have, the above may throw error since it's depricated

link = a_tag['href']
```

**Ouput:**

```
print(link)
http://money.finance.sina.com.cn/bond/issue/sz149412.html
```